# Add Integer into LInked List

Tags: java, linked-list

I am trying to re-study several subjects on data structure inlcuding Linked List. Because it's been too long since my last class works, unfortunately, I am not sure what I am doing wrong with my code. Please give me some advice how to resolve this problem as shown below.

> LinkedList.java

```
package my.linked.list;

public class LinkedList<E> {

    private Listnode<E> items;
    private Listnode<E> lastNode;
    int numItems;

    public LinkedList() {
        items = new Listnode<E>(null);
        lastNode = new Listnode<E>(null);
        numItems = 0;
    }

    public void add(E d) {
        //Listnode<E> temp = new Listnode<E>(d);
        //lastNode.setNext(temp);
        lastNode.setNext(new Listnode<E>(d));
        lastNode = lastNode.getNext();
        numItems++;
    }

    //public void add(int pos){
    //  
    //}

    public void remove(Listnode<E> n) {
        Listnode<E> temp = items;
        if (items == n) {
            items = n.getNext();
        }
        while (temp.getNext() != n) {
            temp = temp.getNext();
        }
        temp.setNext((n.getNext()));
        numItems--;
    }

    //public void remove(int pos) {
    //  
    //}

    public boolean isEmpty() {
        boolean ans = false;
        if (numItems == 0) {
            ans = true;
        }

        return ans;
    }

    public boolean contains() {
        return false;
    }

    public int size() {
        return numItems;
    }

}
```

> MyLinkedListTest.java

```
package my.linked.list;

import java.io.*;

public class MyLinkedListTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        LinkedList myTest = new LinkedList();

        // check whether the linkedlist is empty or not
        boolean ans = false;
        ans = myTest.isEmpty();
        if (ans = true) {
            System.out.println("This Linked List is empty");
        } else {
            System.out.println("This Linked List is not empty");
        }

        // add operation
        for (int i=0; i<5; i++){
            myTest.add(i);
            System.out.println(myTest);
        }
        System.out.println("Current size of myList : " + myTest.size());

    }

}
```

When I run this code, I receive messages below.

This Linked List is empty

```
my.linked.list.LinkedList@667262b6

my.linked.list.LinkedList@667262b6

my.linked.list.LinkedList@667262b6

my.linked.list.LinkedList@667262b6

my.linked.list.LinkedList@667262b6
Current size of myList : 5
```

It looks like that my code doesn't add integer values into the linkedlist data type. Please let me know how to resolve this problem. Thanks so much in advance.

Comment: Please learn how to debug your java code (eg: using eclipse)

Comment: What's the issue? You print the list, not its contents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to override the `toString()` method in the `LinkedList` class, so it displays meaningful information - say, the contents of the list. In its current state, `LinkedList`'s instances are invoking `Object`'s default `toString()` method, which prints a memory address - not very useful. Write something like this in the `LinkedList` class:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    Listnode<E> temp = items;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    while (temp != null) {
        sb.append(temp.getValue()).append(", "); // I'm guessing
        temp = temp.getNext();
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help again. I followed your instructions in my code, but still get some unreasonable results. When I execute System.out.println(myTest.toString()), all I get is "null" somehow. Please let me know what point I am missing here.

Comment: I wrote the general idea to the algorithm (because you didn't post the details of the `Listnode` class). But as long as `toString()` returns a string _and_ you're traversing the list correctly, it should work. It's up to you to traverse the list and decide how to create the string - I don't know the specifics of your implementation

Answer (score 0):

Is the issue that `my.linked.list.LinkedList@667262b6` doesn't look like a list of integers?  That's because you haven't added a `toString()` method to your class that iterates over the list to print its elements.

Answer (score 0):

It actually has added integers into your LinkedList. You can view that by using debug.

System.out.println(Object o) will automatically invoke toString() method of the object you passed in, which is not implemented. So it will print out the pointer to the LInkedList.

`my.linked.list.LinkedList@667262b6` is the pointer to you LinkedList.